# how to stop sbt package command from appending hash to the name of the jar

Tags: scala, plugins, build, publish, sbt-native-packager

I cloned https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager
and then from sbt console ran "package"

and it generated sbt-native-packager/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/sbt-native-packager-0.6.3-dd499ad2b6d0cc108e89827196a32cc6c7a880b0.jar

How do I stop it from generating the hash/sha? or How do I publish it without the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native packager is using the `sbt-git` plugin by default.  It adds the hash so you can release integration builds.

You have two options here:

1. In the sbt console, run `set version := "My-version"` and it will disable the default behavior.
2. Create a tag with the following structure:  `v<version>` and it will use that instead.

You can read more about git versioning on the sbt-git page: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git#versioning-with-git